# Setting text color of EditText

Tags: java, android

I have a dialog that triggers on EditText's context menu. Dialog sets the amount of red, green and blue of EditText. The problem is that runtime error occurs when I click positive button. Items above works fine, they set the color of text in EditText as it should, but rgbDialog don't.

I think that the problem occurs here:

```
            etRed = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etRed);
            etGreen = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etGreen);
            etBlue = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etBlue);
```

But I don't know how to initialize etRed, etGreen and etBlue right. I think that I should place something before findView like

```
etRed = (EditText)Dialog.findViewById(R.id.etRed);
```

But don't know what, because everything is happening in the same method (onContextItemSelected)

```
 @Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch(item.getItemId()){
    case R.id.white:
        temp.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        break;
    case R.id.red:
        temp.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        break;
    case R.id.green:
        temp.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
        break;
    case R.id.rgb:

        AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        dialogBuilder.setTitle("choose the amount of red green and blue");

        LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();

        dialogBuilder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.colors, null));

        dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                etRed = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etRed);
                etGreen = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etGreen);
                etBlue = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etBlue);

                red=etRed.getText().toString();
                green = etGreen.getText().toString();
                blue = etBlue.getText().toString();

                intRed = Integer.parseInt(red);
                intGreen = Integer.parseInt(green);
                intBlue = Integer.parseInt(blue);



                temp.setTextColor(Color.rgb(intRed, intGreen, intBlue));



            }
        });

        dialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", null);

        AlertDialog alertDialog = dialogBuilder.create();
        alertDialog.show();

        break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);

}
```

EditText temp is set like this, and works fine for items above rgb

```
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {


        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.context, menu);

        temp = (EditText)findViewById(v.getId());

        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can have something like below to call findViewById from correct layout:

```
View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.colors, null);
dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView );
```

and when you are calling findViewById in onClick you can have like:

```
etRed = (EditText)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.etRed);
                etGreen = (EditText)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.etGreen);
                etBlue = (EditText)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.etBlue);
```

Check if this helps.